# Reset UITableViewCell position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Course *c = self.courses[indexPath.row];
    UITableViewRowAction *button = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"  -  " handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                    {
                                        [c remove];
                                        [tableView beginUpdates];
                                        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                                        [tableView endUpdates];
                                    }];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor red];
    return @[button];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // you need to implement this method too or nothing will work

}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES; //tableview must be editable or nothing will work...
}
```

How do I reset the position of my cell after the action has been pressed? Currently I'm reloading the cell but this ends up giving the cell a jumpy animation.

Comment: are u trying to delete the row?

Comment: Why do you want to reset your UITableViewCell position? Do you have any other reason and also do you have textField in UITableViewCell?

Comment: @Tj3n not trying to delete the row I want it to snap back to it's original position.

Comment: @user3182143 see above ^ thanks